# Initiate Code in Emacs

Tags: code-snippets, emacs23

I use emacs to mostly code in c++. Is there any way to add a particular piece of code snippet to every new file opoened in Emacs.

For eg:
Suppose i want to create a new file in emacs with name abc.cpp and emacs by default initiates the file with following lines

```
using namespace std;

int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
(defun insert-my-c++-headers ()
  (when (= 0 (buffer-size))
    (insert "using namespace std;\n\nint main(){\n    return 0;\n}\n")))

(add-hook 'c++-mode-hook 'insert-my-c++-headers)
```

Comment: If you want to have the functionality every time you run emacs, add it to the `.emacs` file in your home directory.